# Trying to get the relation using laravel eloquent but get null

Tags: laravel-5

I have two table with the following fields

```
adviser_group
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`organization_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,

organizations
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(191) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
`status` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
```

adviser_group has 1 row,
organization has many row

Using laravel uloquent i'm trying this,

```
  $organization = OrganizationAdviserGroup::with('organization')
    ->where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
    ->get();
```

But what I get, is the `organization = null`

Am i doing it wrong?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel just look at this docs, it's realy simple and easy to understand
[Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships)